# How to Create Dynamic combo boxes in stack panel in wpf, retrieve their values and delete them

Tags: c#, wpf

I want create dynamic comboboxes in wpf stack panel, retrive their values and delete them when the user enters the number in a textbox. Following is the code that I have used, that when the user enter the number in the textbox, (on TextEventChaged) to add comboboxes to the stackpanel(i.e, VehiclesPerday):

```xaml
<TextBox x:Name="NumberOfVehciles" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" TextChanged="NumberOfVehciles_TextChanged"/>
<WrapPanel x:Name="VehiclesPerday" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
</WrapPanel>
```

### BackEnd

```csharp
private void NumberOfVehciles_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

    int _count = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfVehciles.Text.Trim());

    for (int x = 1; x <= _count; x++)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
        cmb.Name = "cmbd" + x.ToString();
        cmb.Height = 40;
        cmb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        cmb.FontSize = 15;
        cmb.Width = 200;
        cmb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        cmb.Margin = new Thickness(50, 40, 0, 0);
        VehiclesPerday.Children.Add(cmb);
    }
}
```

SubmitButton for retrieving data i have tried, it show null value to comboxbox when i debug it

```csharp
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int _count = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfVehciles.Text.Trim());

    for (int x = 1; x <= _count; x++)
    {
        ComboBox _vehicle = (ComboBox)this.VehiclesPerday.FindName("cmbd" + x.ToString());
    }
}
```

And also when the user changes the value in  the textbox, it should remove the combo boxes created in the stack panel and do the vice-versa after changing his value, Eg.
If the user on first go enters 2 in the textbox, 2 combo boxes should be created.
Now if user wants to change the value to 2 to 1 , it should delete the created combo boxes from the stack panel and recreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I've added checking if text in your textbox is number and can be converted to int
- Added call `VehiclesPerday.Children.Clear()` just for tests
- Added `foreach` loop to find the proper `ComboBox` by `Name`

```csharp
private void NumberOfVehciles_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(NumberOfVehciles.Text.Trim(), out int _count))
    {
        VehiclesPerday.Children.Clear(); // for tests
        for (int x = 1; x <= _count; x++)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox // Visual studio simplified object creation here
            {
                Name = "cmbd" + x.ToString(),
                Height = 40,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                FontSize = 15,
                Width = 200,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Margin = new Thickness(50, 40, 0, 0)
            };
            VehiclesPerday.Children.Add(cmb);
        }
    }
}
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(NumberOfVehciles.Text.Trim(), out int _count))
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= _count; x++)
        {
            ComboBox _vehicle = null;
            foreach (ComboBox box in VehiclesPerday.Children)
            {
                if (box.Name == "cmbd" + x.ToString())
                {
                    _vehicle = box; // ComboBox found
                    break;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(_vehicle?.Name ?? "ComboBox not found!"); 
        }
    }
}
```